# Is Android SDK required to test Android APK using Appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

My question is simple , I am using Eclipse IDE

Is it required to install Android SDK to test/run Android app on real device using Appium?

Answer (score 1):

RTFM please

> Add the Android SDK tools folder to your path so you can run android.

you can actually add only a small subset of the tools if you know which ones, adb is one for example.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Sameer.

If you are trying to test android app using appium, you need to have Android SDK installed on your machine.

You can say this is kind of Pre-requisites for Appium!

Comment: i am running on real device so i asked not on simulator/emulator,

Comment: Ok. Thats good you have Q. You're on right track towards new things. Accept answer, if it helps you. So Q also will not be in Active state for long.